# Rotating and making two lines parallel

Tags: c#, rotation, geometry, line, aforge

I have two line segments with points
Line1 = (x1,y1) , ( x2,y2)  ---  smaller
Line2 = (x3,y3) , (x4,y4)   --- bigger

How can I make the Line1(smaller) to rotate and make it parallel to Line2(Bigger)
using either

1) (x1,y1) as fixed point of rotation or
2) (x2,y2) as fixed point of rotation   or
3) center point as fixed point of rotation

I am using C#.NET.
And Aforge.NET Library.

[image: center point as fixed point of rotation]

Thanks

Comment: Treat them as vectors and just draw a new vector with the magnitude of `l1` and the direction of `l2` starting from any of those three points.

Comment: This is more math than programming: I recommend re-posting this over at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BTownTKD: Please note that [crossposting between multiple SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068). You should try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site.

Comment: At any rate, the question has now been crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/299391/264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All operations described below can be expressed as [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation) matrices.

1. Move desired rotation center into the origin.
2. Compute either angle of rotation or directly the rotation matrix. See below.
3. Apply that rotation, as a rotation around the origin.
4. Apply the reverse translation to move the rotation center back to its original position.

You can multiply these three matrices to obtain a single matrix for the whole operation. You can even do so with pen and paper, and hardcode the result into your application.

As to how you compute the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix): The dot product of the two vectors spanning the lines, divided by the length of these vectors, is cos(φ), i.e. the cosine of the angle between them. The sine is ±sqrt(1-cos(φ)²). You only need these two numbers in the rotation matrix, so no need to actually compute angles in terms of performance. Getting the sign right might be tricky, though, so in terms of easy programming you might be better of with two calls to `atan2`, a difference, and subsequent calls to `sin` and `cos`.